# Does `ssh-keyscan` verify the legitimacy of the host(s) it scans?

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-host-key

There are tutorials on the web, such as this one: https://blog.oddbit.com/post/2019-02-24-docker-build-learns-about-secr/

They show you sample code to run `ssh-keyscan` in an automated manner so that subsequent automation steps that depend on SSH can complete successfully. E.g. excerpt from that tutorial:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.0.0-experimental

FROM alpine
RUN apk add --update git openssh

# This is necessary to prevent the "git clone" operation from failing
# with an "unknown host key" error.
RUN mkdir -m 700 /root/.ssh; \
  touch -m 600 /root/.ssh/known_hosts; \
  ssh-keyscan github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts

# This command will have access to the forwarded agent (if one is
# available)
RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:moby/buildkit
```

Is that a good idea? Is there any way for ssh-keyscan to automatically verify the legitimacy of the host it scans? If not, doesn't it become security theatre and defeats the point of SSH's `known_hosts` verification?

Comment: This is an example of "trust on first use" Opinions on TOFU vary - it allows easy setup while protecting future uses - but does have the weakness you mention. For this reason I prefer SSH CA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there any way for ssh-keyscan to automatically verify the legitimacy of the host it scans?

No. How could it? You are using it to *build* the `known_hosts` file that would be used for verification.

> If not, doesn't it become security theatre and defeats the point of SSH's known_hosts verification?

In the example you've shown, it indeed does.

Although the problem isn't that `ssh-keyscan` is being used, but rather when and how it is used. Overall, it isn't any different from getting the regular "Verify unknown host" SSH prompt and blindly typing `yes` without looking at the fingerprint.

If you do it once and keep the resulting `known_hosts` file around, then you still get the same Trust-on-first-use behavior that we all expect from SSH. But if you throw away and regenerate `known_hosts` every time, with no verification against previous runs, then it's going to be a problem whether you use `ssh-keyscan` or not.

In short, deploying a static `known_hosts` file would be much more secure – GitHub's SSH hostkeys certainly don't change often, so there is really no need to re-keyscan them every time.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is technically correct, but there is another way if you know the public fingerprint of the host key. Github [publishes their fingerprint](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints):

```
SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
```

Therefore, you can compare the ssh-keyscan output and verify the host key is valid before adding to the known_hosts file.

```
$ ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com | ssh-keygen -lf - | cut -d' ' -f2
SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8
```

That said, like in the answer above, do it once and deploy the static file.